# Zabbix Trapper items doesn't get result

Tags: host, items, zabbix

I'm using third party template to monitor MySQL Instances. There's two type of services in template zabbix agent and trapper. Most of zabbix agents items got result but I have no idea why trapper items doesn't get result. Could someone assist me.

Answer (score 0):

In order for trapper items to get results, you have to send the values in using `zabbix_sender`. Please see the [official documentation on trapper items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) for more details.